# Retrieve the field name in the parent message with a field descriptor using Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, reflection, protocol-buffers, descriptor

Is it possible with Google [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) to retrieve the field **name** (**not** the field type) of the parent message by using descriptors in C++?

Consider the following minimal example:

```
message MessageHeader {
  string addressee = 1;
}

message Message {
  MessageHeader header = 1;
}
```

I want to retrieve the string `"header.addresse"` with the following function:

```
std::string createFieldQueryFrom(
    const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor* const descriptor)
{
  // TODO(wolters): The descriptor for the containing FIELD is required. Is
  // there a way to retrieve it?
  //
  // containing_descriptor->name() returns "Message", what I want is
  // "header"!
  const google::protobuf::Descriptor* containing_descriptor{
      descriptor->containing_type()};

  // TODO(wolters): Add recursion if able to get the actual attribute name of
  // the containing FIELD.

  return "";
}
```

1. Is this possible, or doesn't a `google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor` instance provide the information required to fulfil that task?
2. If the answer to 1. is *no*: Is this possible at all (if so, can you provide me an example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FieldDescriptor::name()` (e.g. `descriptor->name()` in your example) returns the name of the field. However, this is only "header" or "addressee", not a whole path like "header.addressee".

There's no way to generate a whole path from a single `FieldDescriptor` because it doesn't contain enough information. The type `MessageHeader` could be used in many different places (not just in `Message.header`), so given the descriptor for `addressee` alone there's no way to tell which use site you were looking for.

If you want to keep track of the path of a field while you traverse a message, you'll need to do it manually by maintaining a `stack<FieldDescirptor*>` or similar.